# Prove trig identity: $\csc x\tan x - \cos x= \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I keep hitting seeming dead-ends.

\begin{align*}
\csc\ x \tan\ x - \cos\ x &= \left(\frac{1}{\sin\ x}\right)\left(\frac{\sin\ x}{\cos\ x}\right) - \cos\ x \\
&= \frac{\sin\ x}{(\sin\ x)(\cos\ x)} - \cos\ x \\
&= \frac{\sin\ x}{(\sin\ x)(\cos\ x)} - \frac{(\cos\ x)(\sin\ x)(\cos\ x)}{(\sin\ x)(\cos\ x)} \\
&= \frac{(\cos^2 x)(\sin\ x)}{(\sin\ x)(\cos\ x)} \\
&= \cos\ x
\end{align*}

Thank you!

Comment: Your last line is wrong. You made an error in subtraction from your second last line.

Answer (score 1):

Following your first line, just write

\begin{align*}
\csc t \tan t - \cos t &= \frac{1}{\cos t} - \cos t \\
&= \frac{1 - \cos^2 t}{\cos t}
\end{align*}

from a common denominator. Can you take it from here?

Comment: From there you just replace the numerator with a Pythagorean identity, right? My problem is it's hard for me to recognize that 1-cos^2 is a variation of the Pythagorean identity

Comment: $$\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1\\\frac{a^2}{h^2}+\frac{o^2}{h^2} = 1\\a^2 + o^2 = h^2$$ In other words pythagorean theorem

Comment: @user125736 Yes, you just use a Pythagorean identity. The fact that $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$ is *fundamentally* important, and should always be one of the first things you think about.

Comment: So, does this look right?

csc tan - cos = 1/sin*sin/cos-cos 

= sin - cos^2/sin(cos)

= 1-cos^2/cos

= sin^2/cos

Answer (score 1):

Your method was also not wrong,

L.H.S=$\frac{sinx}{sinxcosx}$-$\frac{cosxsinxcosx}{sinxcosx}$

= $\frac{sinx-cos^2xsinx}{sinxcosx}$

= $\frac{sinx(1-cos^2)}{sinxcosx}$

= $\frac{1-cos^2}{cosx}$

= $\frac{sin^2}{cosx}$=R.H.S